# Microsoft Data Application Block passing data configuration path

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I am currently building an application using Microsoft data application blocks for all db related operations.

I have my config settings for dataconfiguration in web.config file as shown below.

**Web.config**

```
<storageProvider xsi:type="XmlFileStorageProviderData" name="XML File Storage Provider" path="dataConfiguration.config"/>
    <dataTransformer xsi:type="XmlSerializerTransformerData" name="Xml Serializer Transformer">
      < include Types/>
    </data Transformer >
  </configuration Section >
```

**Code**

```
db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(databaseInstance);                
db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sqlQuery);
```

I am able to connect to database, query etc successfully.

But, we have different configuration files on different servers.

Is there any way I can pass path attribute in the code and be able to interact with appropriate database instance by loading that particular config file instead of hard coding it in web.config ??

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use environment variable and load good configuration

1 Create environment variable on your machine Environment

Environment can have different values : Staging, Production etc

2 Use this code to get your variable

```
var variable = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YourNameVariable")
if(variable == "STG") //Staging
{
   //Load your string connection of staging
}
else if(variable == "PRD") //Production
{
   //Load your string connection of production
}
```

3 Create in your file differents section on configuration  and load section target by using you adjusted environment variable.

Comment: Dint quite understood how should i do this. Can you point me to a sample code/example.